# Invoice module to run with commerce module?

Tags: commerce

I'm looking for the right module to include invoicing capabilities with the [Commerce](http://drupal.org/project/commerce) module, but none of them fully fit my needs. Are there any other modules to help with invoicing?

- [Commerce Invoice](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_invoice)
- [Commerce PDF Invoice](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_pdf_invoice)
- [Commerce Invoice Receipt](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_invoice_receipt)

Comment: What do you need that none of these modules provide?

Comment: with commerce_invoice I only get an 'invoice' tab in the order. I don't see how to edit the header and footer of the invoice. I also need to send the invoice by email to the buyer.

Answer (score 5):

The most up2date list of Drupal Commerce invoicing modules can be found at
http://drupal.org/node/1535498